# onCreate() is not getting called after inflating XML File

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am new to Android development and am creating a project with a swipe view has 3 views using fragments. In this class I use an inflater to instantiate the 3 views. I am trying to edit the views from their corresponding activity files(kind of like how a viewcontroller works on IOS) but am having no luck. I was wondering if anyone could guide me on how to control the views I am generating in PageFragment from each corresponding java file.

The Fragment Java code::

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
TextView textView;
private int pageCounter;


public PageFragment(Integer pageCount){
    this.pageCounter = pageCount;
}
public PageFragment(){

}

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   if(pageCounter == 1){
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page1,container,false);

       pageCounter++;
       return view;
   }else if(pageCounter == 2){
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page2,container,false);
       Bundle bundle = getArguments();
       pageCounter++;
       return view;
   }else if(pageCounter == 3){
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page3,container,false);

       pageCounter++;
       return view;
   }

    //this should never run

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment_layout,container,false);
    return view;
}
}
```

The XML for the TextView I am trying to change the text for:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    tools:context="com.example.aryamirshafii.resumewriterexcelandroidversion.page3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:text="you are on page 3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Java File for the XML Activity I am trying to change

```
public class page1 extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final dataManager myDataManager = new dataManager();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final Context context = textView.getContext();
    textView.setText("Hello World");


}


}
```

[image: The ScreenShot]

In short, I want the textView that says "you are on page 1" to instead say "Hello World" from the page1.java class. Any assistance in the right direction towards achieving this would be appreciated.

Comment: wats your content in activitypage1.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Your Fragment and Activity are both loading `R.layout.activity_page1`.

Your Activity needs to load a different XML that contains a ViewPager.

And `PageFragment` should not load 3 different layouts. You can use one layout per 3 Fragments each, and a `FragmentPagerAdapter` class with that if-else block to `return new Page1Fragment()`, for example, and you use `viewPager.setAdapter()` with it from the Activity.

You can also probably use one of the [Android Studio Activity templates to give you a Tabbed Activity Layout](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates.html#TabbedActivity)